# Is MQTT efficient in case of real time communication beetween server and thousands of clients?

Tags: mqtt

I have an issue where I have backend server and thousands of clients.
Each client has its own topic in MQTT.

Communication is bi-directional: clients can ask backend for smth, backend can respond or notify by some action in real-time.

How should I scale my backend subscribers to process a huge amount of messages from MQTT?

As MQTT implements pub/sub pattern, when I will scale subscribers to process more messages at the same time by adding one more instance, it will subscribe to the same topic and receive the same message as other subscribers.

Pub/sub scaling issue: Subscriber1, Subscriber2 will get Message1, then Subscriber1, Subscriber2 will get Message2.

It is opposite to AMQP when I have a consumer of the queue instead of pub/sub.

Consumer1 will get Message1, Consumer2 will get Message2, so scaling is efficient.

So is it a good choice for backend server to use MQTT in case of real-time communication with a huge amount of clients? How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [shared subscriptions](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901250), a feature of MQTT v5, address your concern:

> Like a Non‑shared Subscription, it has a Topic Filter and Subscription Options; however, a publication that matches its Topic Filter is **only sent to one** of its subscribing Sessions. Shared Subscriptions are useful where several consuming Clients share the processing of the publications in parallel.